# Will a nandroid backup save me from a bad upgrade?

Tags: updates, backup, ota-update, nandroid

I have a Rezound on 4.03, and verizon has pushed an update to it today. I have delayed the install because there's little information about it. What little I have found claim it make the phone unstable.

I made a nandroid backup, with the default options. That means:
[Boot], [System], [data], and [cache] were selected.
[recovery], [sd-ext], and [.android_secure] were not selected.

My question is, if this OTA update does make my phone worse, will simply restoring the backup pretty much guarantee a seemless "undo"? Or is it possible the update could change something that I can't revert?

Comment: The update might include a "radio image" (the hardware layer, one could say) which is not included with a Nandroid backup. It could also include a "recovery image" which you didn't include with your backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update might include a new radio-firmware (see: [What is radio firmware?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/70/16575); basically you can think of it as the "hardware-layer" or an API to give the installed (Android) system access to the hardware), which is not included with a Nandroid backup. It could also include a "recovery-image" (see: [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode)), which you did not include with your backup.

For the latter, you could simply include it with your Nandroid backup. The radio-image is a different thing: I know of no method to extract/backup it from a given device. You could, however, check which radio version is currently installed with your device, and see if you can get a "RUU" (Radio Unit Update) specifically for that.

Comment: Thank you, I will just have to find a good way to turn off the OTA notifications.

Comment: Some custom roms have an app named 'fota-kill' for that. Unfortunately, I couldn't find it on the playstore -- but maybe [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1579154) has it somewhere for download :)