# Can I flash a ROM of another Android version?

Tags: rom-flashing

I'm currently having Android Lollipop and wanting to flash a Android 6.0 ROM. Would that brick my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question.
In order to flash a rom with higher Android version you need to

- make sure the rom is for your device
- flash new bootloader
- flash new radio

Note: i recommend upgrading Android version with the OTA update from your OEM (Samsung, HTC, ... etc) because you cannot mess up. And then flashing the rom.

Then follow the usual steps for flashing any rom which are

- make sure rom can be flashed on your device
- wipe (optionally not including internal storage)
- flash rom
- flash gapps if not included in rom
- reboot

And if you want Root

- find a SuperSU version that your ROM supports
- reboot to recovery
- flash SuperSU zip
- reboot

IMPORTANT : after flashing twrp may ask you to root your device Select NO

Note: you know that a rom can be flashed on your device only if your device's codename is in the name of the zip file. For example : paranoidandroid6.0.1_hammerhead.zip
 Here hammerhead is the device codename , specifically nexus 5.

Make sure to research before doing anything.

Comment: What is a bootloader, radio. Why should I flash it, and how? Thanks :)

Comment: @Yayy bootloader explained : http://www.androidcentral.com/what-is-android-bootloader , radio explained  : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-is-radio-firmware, you flash them like a regular zip , every device comes with one installed , when upgrading software ,bootloader and radio may need to upgrade too. That's why i recommend to upgrade with the OTA from you OEM, it is much easier

Comment: What if there is no OTA for my device yet? :o

Comment: @Yayy than you either get the radio and bootloader from the team that make the rom or you don't get it at all

Comment: @Yayy Sometimes you don't need to flash them at all. For example: i have a Nexus 5 with Android 6.0 , in order to flash 7.0 rom i don't need to flash bootloader and radio. Now i don't really know if this is device specific or if they are included in the rom. Once again research beforehand and ask on xda forums